# download images with node.js request

Tags: node.js, image, request

I have a script that get all images's url from database and download these images through of request module. The problem is that when I have more than 400 images, the process stop over 480 and doesn't go on. The problem isn't the url because sometime stop over 450 or 467...

```
var process = {
            error: 0,
            success: 0,
            getTotal: function() {
                return this.error + this.success;
            }
        };

        var request = require('request');
        var maxLength = 10 // 10mb

        var callback = function(error, success) {
            if (error) {
                ++process.error;
            } else {
                ++process.success;
            }

            console.log(process.getTotal());

        };

        Photo.find({limit: 500}).exec(function (err, images){
            if (err || images.length === 0) {
                return err;
            }

            for (var image in images) {

                request({
                    url: images[image].url,
                    encoding: null
                }, function(err, res, body) {
                    //console.log(file.url);
                    if (err) {
                        return callback(res, null);
                    }

                    if (res.headers['content-length'] > maxLength*1024*1024) {
                        return callback(new Error('Image too large.'), null)
                    }

                    if (!~[200, 304].indexOf(res.statusCode)) {
                        return callback(new Error('Received an invalid status code.'), null);
                    }

                    if (!res.headers['content-type'].match(/image/)) {
                        return callback(new Error('Not an image.'), null);
                    }

                    callback(false, true);
                });
            }
        });
```

Also I have tested with a limit 5000 images and the process stop over 4800.

Comment: The problem is that on the `for` block, you are executing the `request()` function that many times. So your code is trying to process all those images at the same time. Might I suggest using some promise library, such as [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird).

Comment: I have test the following module:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/then-request
this has request with promise and happened the same. I forgot to say that I'm using sails js and this run with sails's console as a service.

Comment: You can still use Bluebird, the `map()` function will help, specially using the `concurrency` option. That way you make sure you are processing `x` amount of images at a time.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
var myConcurrency = 200;
var promises = [];

/**
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
var getImage = function(image) {
    return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
        request({
            //...
        }, function(err, res) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            return resolve(res);
        })
    }
}

var callback = function() {};

/**
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
var handleImage = function(res) {

    if (res.headers['content-length'] > maxLength*1024*1024) {
        return callback(new Error('Image too large.'), null)
    }

    if (!~[200, 304].indexOf(res.statusCode)) {
        return callback(new Error('Received an invalid status code.'), null);
    }

    if (!res.headers['content-type'].match(/image/)) {
        return callback(new Error('Not an image.'), null);
    }

}

Photo.find({limit: 500}).exec(function (err, images){
    if (err || images.length === 0) {
        return err;
    }
    Promise
        .map(images, function() {
            return getImage();
        })
        .map(handleImage, {concurrency: myConcurrency});

});
```

Comment: It happened the same. I have decided take one result on the query. So, this way I remove the loop.